# How to make this kind of rounded border-radius?

Tags: css

[image]

I am trying to make this design I found on [Dribbble](https://dribbble.com/shots/7012405-Music-App-UI).

I have made this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/vivekpmcodepen/pen/KKvEMgR?editors=1100) but I can't figure out how to make the sides rounded. Just like shown in image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="footer2"></div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="download"></div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
body {
    background: #e3e3e3;
}

.container {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 400px;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.footer2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: #F3D44F;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  background: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.download {
  position: absolute;
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
  background: #000;
  top: -30px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  outline: 20px solid #F3D44F;
}
```

Comment: Try this ```<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-3 0 9 3">
  <path d="m-2 0L-1 0 0 0Q.5 0 .5.5a1 1 0 001 1a1 1 0 001-1Q2.5 0 3 0L4 0 5 0Q6 0 6 1L6 2Q6 3 5 3L-2 3Q-3 3-3 2L-3 1Q-3 0-2 0" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="0.1" fill="#ffffff"/>
</svg>``` You can change the width of it with css.

Comment: And the height if needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. I've been trying to make it work as they said in two posts. But in that, it was using radial-gradient and it was horizontal also couldn't get it to work.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help!

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use clip path. Take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

Comment: Do you have any related example as I want?

Comment: I dont have an example that I have done, cause I dont ever use cut path! But I will go look for something similar or make it myself. Just a minute.

Comment: Have you tried using svg?